# How to use Python to split Excel worksheet with rows containing \n into individual rows?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a spreadsheet with some rows that contain \n that need to be broken apart into individual rows.

I am able to open the sheet with openpyxl and convert the worksheet to a pandas dataframe, but I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to split the rows.

Input:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Note that row 7 became row 7 & row 8 - that is the desired behavior for any row that has \n.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

EDIT: My crappy original code is below; this is as far as I've gotten and I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

wb = load_workbook(filename="<filename>")
ws = wb["Page 1"]

# load worksheet into pandas dataframe
wsdf = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)

# create output wb/ws
output_wb = Workbook()
output_ws = output_wb.active
output_ws.title = "output"

# identify rows where crlf > 0
toBeSplit = []
pos = 0
for row in wsdf.iloc[:,1]:
    #print ( pos, " ", str(row).count("\n") )
    if ( str(row).count("\n") > 0 ):
        toBeSplit.append(pos)
    pos = pos + 1

print ( "Rows to be split: ", toBeSplit)

# write output
output_wb.save('<filename>')
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you have so far, in order to make it easier to test things out?

Comment: You can do this in excel natively https://trumpexcel.com/split-multiple-lines/

Comment: Beside your main problem, I have a suggestion: you can use `pandas.read_excel()` method to load your excel file. more pythonic, more options to handle

Comment: i agree with @Alireza pandas should be able to handle this much easier than openpyxl. if you have got some excel formatting you wish to capture, openpyxl is great, but when it comes to munging and slicing, I think Pandas outshines openpyxl. hopefully, u found a way to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks everyone.   I have no problem loading the data into pandas, it's really the splitting of the rows that I'm confounded by. I'm basically trying to split any row that looks like row 7 (on my input) into rows 7+8 on my output side.   Any thoughts?